# Server responds with file not found but doesn't throw 404 error

Tags: amazon-lightsail

I am trying to redirect to a custom 404 page when a file is not found. However my server is responding with "File Not Found" but doesn't say 404 and doesn't redirect.

I am using amazon Lightsail using the LAMP bitnami stack.

It redirects successfully on a 403 error, and it redirects successfully when I try to navigate to a invalid directory. The invalid files however don't get handled correctly. They just merely print "File not found"

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
ErrorDocument 400 https://example.com/error.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/error.php
ErrorDocument 403 https://example.com/error.php
ErrorDocument 500 https://example.com/error.php
Options -Indexes

# SPELLING
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
    CheckSpelling off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.
Added this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /error.php [L,R=301]
```

Now it works for anyone curious.